# How to enable two factor authentication

Tags: centos, authentication, radius

I am using CentOS 6.3 and want to enable ssh RADIUS authentication.

Right now my server is directly authenticated with RADIUS server. I want the server to authenticate with unix credentials first and after that to do authentication via RADIUS.

I'm pretty sure about that I have set something inside the file `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, but I'm not sure what it is I should set.

The configuration I'm using now is:

```
auth       required   /lib64/security/pam_radius_auth.so
auth       required   /lib64/security/pam_nologin.so
account    required   /lib64/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
password   required   /lib64/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
session    required   /lib64/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
session    required   /lib64/security/pam_limits.so
session    optional   /lib64/security/pam_console.so
```

But it is directly asking for RADIUS password only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now my setting is
auth required /lib64/security/pam_radius_auth.so
auth include  system-auth
auth required /lib64/security/pam_nologin.so
account       required   /lib64/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
password      required   /lib64/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
session       required   /lib64/security/pam_stack.so service=system-auth
session required         /lib64/security/pam_limits.so
session optional         /lib64/security/pam_console.so

In which it ask for radius password first and after that unix password. How can i make unix password first and Radius second.

Answer (score 0):

Pls open 2 ssh sessions, one for editting pam file, the other is used in case PAM misconfiguration, and it locks you out

Pls try this config:

```
auth required /lib64/security/pam_radius_auth.so
auth include  system-auth
auth required /lib64/security/pam_nologin.so
..
```

Comment: If you need unix authen 1st, then just change the order

Comment: Thanx dear.. What about solaris sparc version, In solaris pam configuration file is /etc/pam.conf Any idea for setting unix and after that radius authentication
Thanx in advance

Comment: Any idea to set banner for the unix and radius password ?
Such as provide unix password and provide radius password?